# How can I align flex items with gap in a row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two `<div>` rows with `display: flex;` each of them contains a couple of children `<div>` items. In the example below, you can see that in the first row there a 2 items (green boxes labeled "item") which are flexed in the ratio `6/3`. In the second there are 4 items which are flexed in the ratio `2/2/2/3`.

Now I would expect the last item in each row (the ones with `flex: 3;`) to be perfectly aligned, which it is, unless I add a `gap: X px;`.

---

How can I include this `gap` in the calculation so that the items with the same width are aligned based on their `flex` property?
Or graphically simplified in the following snippet: How can I align the red borders?

```css
.flex {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px; // <- malefactor that destroys my layout
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-2 {
  flex: 2;
}

.item-3 {
  flex: 3;
}

.item-6 {
  flex: 6;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item item-6" style="border-right: 2px solid red;">item</div>
    <div class="item item-3">item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item item-2">item</div>
    <div class="item item-2">item</div>
    <div class="item item-2" style="border-right: 2px solid red;">item</div>
    <div class="item item-3">item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS grid is made for such configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is the usage of CSS-Grid. You simply divide the grid into a 9-column grid which automatically takes the gaps into account:

```css
.d-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
  column-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 25px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.item-3 {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.item-6 {
  grid-column: span 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-grid">
  <div class="item item-6" style="border-right: 2px solid red;">item</div>
  <div class="item item-3">item</div>
  <div class="item item-2">item</div>
  <div class="item item-2">item</div>
  <div class="item item-2" style="border-right: 2px solid red;">item</div>
  <div class="item item-3">item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the multiple possible solutions is to wrap some of the items in another **flex** div.
See in the code bellow with the class `flex-item`:

```css
.flex {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px; // <- malefactor that destroys my layout
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-2 {
  flex: 2;
}

.item-3 {
  flex: 3;
}

.item-6 {
  flex: 6;
}

.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
    <div>
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="item item-6" style="border-right: 2px solid red;">item</div>
        <div class="item item-3">item</div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="flex-item item-6 white">
          <div class="item item-2">item</div>
          <div class="item item-2">item</div>
          <div class="item item-2" style="border-right: 2px solid red;">item</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-3">item</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Another solution would involve the use of **css grid**, you can setup a grid with 9 columns and assign the column span accordingly:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.item-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.item-3 {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.item-6 {
  grid-column: span 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
      <div class="item item-6" style="border-right: 2px solid red;">item</div>
      <div class="item item-3">item</div>
      <div class="item item-2">item</div>
      <div class="item item-2">item</div>
      <div class="item item-2" style="border-right: 2px solid red;">item</div>
      <div class="item item-3">item</div>
</div>
```

With this solution you can also use `grid-gap: 20px` instead of `grid-column-gap: 20px` if you want the same gap between the rows.